# Linear Forms on Subspaces of a finite Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$, $M$ a linear subspace of $V$, with $x$ a vector not in $M$.

Show that there exists a linear form $f$ on V such that $f(x)\neq0$ while $f(y) = 0$ for any $ y \in M$.

Stuck here. Tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a basis $E$ for $M$. Since $x$ is not in $M$, $\{x\} \cup M$ is a linearly independent set. Extend this to a basis $B$ of $V$. Now, you can define your linear functional directly at the basis by specifying $f(x)=1$ and $f(b)=0$ for all $b \in B, b \neq x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be a base of $W$ and $\{x,e_{n+1},...,e_{m}\}\subseteq V$ such that $\{e_1,...,e_n,x,e_{n+1},...,e_m\}$ is a base of $V$ (Why is $\{e_1,...,e_n,x\}$ LI?).

Let $\{e^*_1,...,x^*,...,e^*_m\}$ its dual basis. The linear form $x^*$ satisfies the thesis.